# Is there a way to return a specific type from a function that can return multiple?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to have a function that can return multiple types and the return value is assigned to one of the types from the union.

```
interface Alpha {}
interface Beta {}
interface Gamma {}

const hello = (arg): Alpha | Beta | Gamma => {
  if (arg === 'Alpha') return {} as Alpha;
  if (arg === 'Beta') return {} as Beta;
  if (arg === 'Gamma') return {} as Gamma;
  throw new Error('meow');
};

const x = hello('Beta');
```

Currently `x` can be `Alpha | Beta | Gamma` but the runtime knows it is `Beta`. Is it possible for `x` to know it is of type `Beta`?

**Update**

Here's an example with a `Recipe` interface with a date and it's nullable, and a `RecipeQuery` that allows you to query for non-nullable results.

```
interface Recipe {
  date: Date | null
}

interface RecipeQuery {
  date: {
    null: boolean
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do an overload that says if the query is `null` `false` that the date in `Recipe` will now always be a `string`, not a union.

```
function Query(q: Merge<RecipeQuery, { date: { null: false } }>): Merge<Recipe, { date: Date }>;
```

This doesn't work correctly.

Essentially what I want is this:

```
function query(recipeQuery: RecipeQuery) {
  if (recipeQuery.date.null === true) return { date: null } as Recipe;
  if (recipeQuery.date.null === false) return { date: new Date } as Merge<Recipe, { date: Date }>;
  throw new Error('');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it. My favorite one would be to use a "mapping type":

```
interface HelloMapping {
  'Alpha': Alpha
  'Beta': Beta
  'Gamma': Gamma
}

const hello = <T extends keyof HelloMapping>(arg: T)
  : HelloMapping[T] => {
  if (arg === 'Alpha') return {} as Alpha;
  if (arg === 'Beta') return {} as Beta;
  if (arg === 'Gamma') return {} as Gamma;
  throw new Error('meow');
};
```

You can also do via overloads:

```
function hello(arg: 'Alpha'): Alpha
function hello(arg: 'Beta'): Beta
function hello(arg: 'Gamma'): Gamma
function hello(arg: 'Alpha' | 'Beta' | 'Gamma') {
  if (arg === 'Alpha') return {} as Alpha;
  if (arg === 'Beta') return {} as Beta;
  if (arg === 'Gamma') return {} as Gamma;
  throw new Error('meow');
};
```

Comment: Hey, this is amazing. The strings example does make it a little more simplified. I'm struggling something a little more complex, I added an example above.

Comment: @Grassator mapping example won't work if the interfaces are non-trivial, so I think in this case only function overloads work