# Typescript: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' in return value of function

Tags: typescript

Basically I'm interested why does this example work:

```
interface Alpha {}
interface Beta {}

interface HelloMapping {
  'Alpha': Alpha
  'Beta': Beta  
}

const hello = <T extends keyof HelloMapping>(arg: T): HelloMapping[T] => 
{
  if (arg === 'Alpha') return {} as Alpha;
  return {} as Beta;
};

const a = hello('Alpha') // a is of interface Alpha
```

But this one doesn't:

```
interface HelloMapping2 {
  'Alpha': string
  'Beta': number
}

const hello2 = <T extends keyof HelloMapping2>(arg: T): HelloMapping2[T] => 
{
  if (arg === 'Alpha') return "42" as string
  return 42 as number
};
```

It errors with `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'` in the first line of function code.
The only difference is changing interfaces to `string` and `number` types

Please note, I know how to make that work with function overloads but I am curious why it does not work.

Comment: `interface Alpha {} & interface Beta {} === {}`, `string & number === never`

Comment: @zerkms Thank you! It looks like the contrived example with interfaces fooled me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one works for the reason pointed out by @zerkms: `Alpha` and `Beta` are the same type.  TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), not nominal.  If `Alpha` and `Beta` have the same shape (i.e., [the empty type `{}`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces)), they are the same type, despite having different *names*.  So let's ignore that example because it rests on an accidental type identity.

---

The reason the second example won't work is that generics do not get narrowed by control flow analysis (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)).  The check `arg === 'Alpha'` doesn't convince the compiler that `T` is now `'Alpha'`.  It's generally unsound to do so; if there are multiple possible values of type `T`, then checking one value of type `T` doesn't necessarily have implications on any other.

There's currently no clean solution for this, although suggestions have been made that might address it. One suggestion is to allow you to specify that a generic type [must be exactly *one literal member* of a union](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), so that any values of type `T` that exist must be identical, and you can safely narrow all of them when you narrow one.

If you want to see this implemented or the situation addressed, you might want to head over to those GitHub issues and give them a  or describe your use case if it's particularly compelling.

So, what to do in the meantime?

---

The answer that always works to allow the implementation to compile with out error is to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) (they are what I call "morally" equivalent, since overloads essentially assert the types of parameters and returns to be the those in the implementation signature).  In your case they would look like this (I know you know how to do this, but others who come later might not):

```
const helloAssert = <T extends keyof HelloMapping>(arg: T): HelloMapping[T] => {
    if (arg === 'Alpha') {
        return "42" as HelloMapping[T];
    }
    return 42 as HelloMapping[T];
};

function helloOverload<T extends keyof HelloMapping>(arg: T): HelloMapping[T];
function helloOverload(arg: keyof HelloMapping) {
    if (arg === 'Alpha') {
        return "42"
    }
    return 42;
}
```

These are somewhat unsafe, though, because although they'd catch completely crazy errors (e.g., `return true`), they wouldn't catch simple mixups (e.g., change `===` to `!==` in the test).

---

Sometimes, though, you can avoid these unsafe solutions by abandoning control flow analysis and represent the generic type manipulation directly: an object `o` of type `O` and a key `k` of type `K` yields a readable property `o[k]` of type `O[K]`, even if `O` and `K` are generic:

```
const helloMap = <T extends keyof HelloMapping>(arg: T): HelloMapping[T] =>
    ({ Alpha: "42", Beta: 42 })[arg];
```

So you give an actual `HelloMapping` instance to `helloMap()` and index into it.  This might not work for all use cases, of course, but it's sometimes useful to do things in a way that works with the compiler instead of against it.

---

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIQDYYPYFk4AOBoA5sgN4BQyNyA5AIIYEAWcdAXMgM5hSnVadAEIQw7LiACuAWwBG0SgF9KlBNhC9kLTDgbdu0MMgC8yADwAVZBAAekEABNuyANYQAnthhpdeQsQgJAB8ABRwUCRclgCUXOhY-kSkANqWALqmwRSCNMA+4ZGmJmaMzGx0MTm0NchQYlJQIMgARAAsAEwtyHAuCTj4yUFp6QDcucgqNfVgjc2dPX1+g4EkI+NK45QwUiAIYMAa2n4A8gBu0DhwjlY29hBOLu5ePv1Jq2ERUcix8csBqQy4x2ewORx0iXOl2w10K32e3l8iRWpCqVBq+WQcOKpSYrHYaIm0waTVanRaEymtBmc2QnQ2qnUmmMEIGhFMFmsdgczjcnkRbxRQU+kWicSRbKGawyWQmoXIyDxbC47S6ABpkKJxFwFkoYikvmNKEA)

Answer (score 0):

As @zerkms rightly pointed in his comment the first example only works because the interfaces `Alpha` & `Beta` are empty and their intersection (which is a return type of the function) is also an empty object. As soon as you try adding properties to any of them it will stop working. So in reality it's no better than second example.

The context for this question is this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54443711/2874705

I really liked the idea of using the mapping to have a nicely inferred returned valued from a function. It could work with a bit of adjustment:

```
interface Alpha {
    a: boolean
}
interface Beta {
    b: string
}

interface HelloMapping {
    'Alpha': Alpha
    'Beta': Beta
}

const helloValues: HelloMapping = {
    'Alpha': {
        a: true
    },
    'Beta': {
        b: '42'
    }
}

const hello = <T extends keyof HelloMapping>(arg: T) => {
    return helloValues[arg]
};

const a = hello('Alpha') // a has interface Alpha
```

The other idea is to use function overload like in the answer I linked above.